# Add bracing to I-Joist

Tags: walls, basement, framing, joists, blocking

I am trying to build a non-load bearing wall parallel to the I-joist in my basement.  I know that I need to add bracing to span the gap between the wall and the joist, but I am slightly confused as to where to nail it.  Most places had suggested to face nail through the I-joist and then toe nail the brace to the rim joist.  But this is not level.  This is what I was thinking of doing.  Does this make sense?  Can I use screws on the the rim boards instead of nails?

[image]

Comment: ...or you could just nail/screw a thick piece (1-1/2" at a guess, aka 2x lumber) from the top of the sill plate to the bottom of the I-Joist, if "brown lumber is old, "greenish wood looking lumber is new" is your color code. Unless you are desperate for that inch and a half on top of the wall, anyway...

Answer (score 2):

End nailing into the brace will not be a useful and strong joint. Instead do something like the following where the brace is made of 2x lumber. Notch it as shown and set on edge and toe nailed from each side. Much stronger.

[image]

Comment: Agree completely, and wanted to note that screws (used appropriately) would work as well as nails.

Comment: also screws may be easier to fit (especially at the joist end)

Comment: All depends on the working space, tools available, and other factors. I would use screws myself in many cases like this except that if there is room for a pneumatic nailer it can make the toe nailing operation a piece of cake.

Comment: So, here's a question about the toe nailing - there is just shy of 1" of the joist to nail into.  Its the diagram showing putting in 3 nails into the joist? It doesn't seem like it'd fit without running into each other or splitting the wood.  Also, what types of screws would you use?

Comment: It almost seems like if I didn't put it on edge, I could instead use 2 2x4's stacked.  Then I could put 2 screws into the end of the the one on the joist and then nail the 2 boards together (which also alleviates having to notch the 2x4's to the right size)

Comment: Nailing or screwing into the end grain of the wood where you expect the direction of force to be inline with the axis of the screw or nail is a bad idea. You almost always want to have the nails or screws situated so that they are in shear (perpendicular to) with the direction of the force.

Comment: You really need to use your judgement about the use of the toe nailing. If there really is only an inch on the ledge of the I-joist then pre-drill a pilot hole up from the bottom of the joist flange and screw up into the ends of the 2x4. Also don't balk at the thought of making the notches. This is a standard construction practice and is done all the time when there are strange fit conditions. Don't take shortcut just because something seems too involved.